# Redirect to previous page after login?

Tags: url, redirect, authentication, joomla2.5

Eg: My place at profile page, when session expired, i refresh, redirect to login page. How to redirect to profile page after login?. Im using joomla 2.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to redirect to the previous page after login.

```
$app                = JFactory::getApplication();

/*Return Url*/
$url = base64_encode(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_test&view=products));

/*Login Url*/
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='.$url);

$app->Redirect($link);
```